# ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper Razor Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am currently learning ASP.NET MVC and am presented with the following code snippet:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @placeholder = "First name"})
```

I understand that the lambda expression refers to the model as **m**, but what is the second argument? It seems to be an anonymous type, but my main question is why is there an **@** character in front of placeholder?

Comment: The second argument is an object to pass additional HTML attributes. In this case you want to add the `placeholder` HTML attribute to the input. The @ sign is needed if you use a reserved word (keyword). Otherwise you would get a compilation error. Although, "placeholder" is no keyword, so it is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 5):

The second argument is `htmlAttributes` which you can use to add additional attributes to the HTML that is generated by the helper (@Html.TextBoxFor is a HTML helper).

The generated code for your example will be along the lines of:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @placeholder = "First name"})
<input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First name" />
```

If you want, you can add more attributes and they will also be added to the generated tag:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder = "First name", @class="my_text_box_class" })
<input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First name" class="my_text_box_class" />
```

It's also possible to override the value of the textbox using `Value` (upper case V!):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { placeholder = "First name", Value="John Johnson"})
<input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First name" value="John Johnson" />
```

The reason for the **@** symbol is for when you want an attribute named exactly as a C# [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx).  class, private, namespace etc.  It is a way to make the C# complier stop interpreting it as it's C# meaning.  The @ symbol is only required for these reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

The `@placeholder` syntax tells the razor engine that you want to assign a value to an html attribute on the element that will be rendered by the helper.  As such, if you needed to set a class to the textbox as well, your anonymous type would change to:

```
new { @placeholder = "First name", @class = "BoldText" }
```

As for why you use `@`, the `@` allows you to use reserved keywords as variable names.  If you tried to use

```
class = "BoldText"
```

you would receive a runtime error in your view since `class` is a reserved keyword in C#.  The prefacing `@` ensures that this doesn't happen and is considered a "best practice". The `@` would only be necessary before `class`, not `placeholder`.

Comment: @Nicolas : The @ sign is needed if you use a reserved word (keyword). Otherwise you would get a compilation error. Although, "placeholder" is no keyword, so it is not needed in this case.

Comment: @Styxxy in this case you'd receive a runtime exception, not a compilation error since this is in a razor view.

Comment: I +1'd so that your efforts weren't fruitless.  Enjoy

Comment: @Coulton much appreciated and likewise

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter expects an anonymous object for the `htmlAttributes` you would like to specify in your input.

You use the `@` symbol to tell the razor engine that you're specifying an `htmlAttribute` and not a reserved keyword.